# SharePoint 2010 Web part Branding Issue

Tags: 2010, branding

I'm having an issue where the branding on a web part representing a document library is off. Web parts representing custom lists do not have this problem. I am using Kyle Schaeffer's v5 master page, with no additional styling of the web parts.

[image: web part formatting]

Comment: I would go through and figure out the differences in CSS classes between the document library webparts and the custom list webparts, and see if any custom css touches those classes.

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case, it was an unrelated style causing the web part styling to behave unexpectedly.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this answer.